# which preposition(in/for) should I use to collocate with the verb "rival"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. Ships can't rival planes **for** speed.
> 2. He could rival others **in** skill
> 3. The sun rivals the moon **in** beauty.

Two different prepositions (for/in) are used in the example sentences,"for speed" and "in beauty". *Speed* and *beauty* are both nouns, why they collocate with different prepositions?
Could I say "in speed" or "for beauty"?

Comment: I can barely read those.  The first one is full of typos. Please clean up your spelling and punctuation and try to fix your grammar, too. And follow "behind" is wrong.

Comment: The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rival) entry shows it as an alternative usage: *No computer can rival a human brain for/in complexity.*

Comment: This question needs a serious amount of editing to correct numerous errors. Spelling, punctuation, use of capitals etc.